# php: change value of variable based on dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, variables, switch-statement

Learning PHP and having an issue that I can't figure out. I have read that PHP only has scope for functions, so I'm not sure why my switch statement isn't changing the value of variables.

Goal: to change the mysql SELECT statement based on user selection of drop-down.

Form:

```
    <form action="contacts_show.php" method="POST">
    <select name="grade" id="grade">
    <option value="all">All Levels</option>
    <option value="elementary">Elementary</option>
    <option value="middle">Middle</option>
    <option value="senior">Senior</option>
<input type="submit" name="browse" id="browse" value="Browse" />
</form>
```

PHP (edited to shorten code):

```
$levelSelected = $_POST['grade'];

if ($levelSelected == "all") {
    $querySelect = "SELECT * FROM teachers ORDER BY school ASC";
} else {
    $querySelect = "SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE school LIKE %$levelSelected% ORDER BY school ASC";
}

$query = $querySelect;
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
confirm_query($result);
```

the confirm_query function, if needed:

```
    function confirm_query($result_set) {
    if (!$result_set) {
        die("Database query failed.");
    }
}
```

When "All Levels" from drop-down is selected, code runs as expected. When any other option is selected, my confirm_query function states that the query fails.

I'm not sure why the variable's values are not switching.

Comment: `LIKE %elementary%` => `LIKE '%elementary%'` and do the same for the others. You're not checking for DB errors. If that still doesn't work, then it's also a scope issue.

Comment: You can get the exact error from mysqli by using `mysqli_error` or you can have mysqli throw exceptions.

Comment: You're trying to parse strings not integers you should get an error.
Please try '%all%' instead of %all%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

Change `LIKE %elementary%` to => `LIKE '%elementary%'` and do the same for the others.

You need to wrap the pattern match in quotes, and as per the manual:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

> mysql> SELECT 'David!' LIKE '%D%v%';
>   mysql> SELECT 10 LIKE '1%';

You're also not checking for DB errors.

Add `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`

If that still doesn't work, then it's also a scope issue.
Pass the connection to your function, do **not** make it global.